# How to set 'enabled' property for gesture recognizers in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I can't set the 'enabled' property with gesture recognizers. I tried creating recognizers both programmatically and by adding an `@IBAction` in `Xcode` and connecting it by control drag to the code.

I try to use properties like this:

```
swipeUpOccurred(swipeUp: UISwipeGestureRecognizer).enabled = false
```

But it is showing error:

> Value of type '(UISwipeGestureRecognizer) ->' does not have member 'enabled'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to set the [`isEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624220-isenabled) on the action of `UIGestureRecognizer`. Instead of that you need to create the Outlet of `UIGestureRecognizer` if you want to access it inside your `ViewController`, so create one Outlet of that gesture with its specific type then set `isEnabled` property to `true/false` when ever you need to `enable/disabled` it.

```
@IBOutlet var swipeGest: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!
```

Now use `isEnabled` property with it.

```
self.swipeGest.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: It turned out to be that simple... Thanks!

Comment: @AntonPlatonov Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

It was renamed. Try `isEnabled` instead.

```
swipeUpOccurred(swipeUp: UISwipeGestureRecognizer).isEnabled = false
```

Comment: In this case the warning is: Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'isEnabled'

Answer (score 0):

[isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624220-isenabled) should be used instead